# Change Leaflet Map Layer/Terrain Style

Tags: leaflet, kml, mapbox

I'm going to show KML file using Leaflet's plugins named Omnivore KML (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/omnivore-kml/)

I've read the tutorial, implement the source code, and it generate a map like this :

[image: Generated KML Map using Omnivore KML]

But now, what i want to do is changing it's layer/terrain style to be like this :

[image]

How can i achive that?

I've read that there's another Leaflet Plugin named Leaflet Bing Layer (https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-bing-layer) to show map's layer/terrain like the image above.

Can i combine Omnivore and Leaflet Bing Layer to achieve this?

Or i can just add some code into my leaflet javascript code to change it's layer/terrain style?

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be Bing maps (apparently they don't offer XYZ tiles), you can use ESRI World Imagery:

```js
L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
    }).addTo(map);
```

[Source (has many more basemaps with code)](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)